# WriteAfterEnd error when saving log during testing of websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I m building command line websocket test with NodeJs.

I define filestream at the top of the file

```
const fs = require('fs');
let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(log_path);
```

I m using the code below to test websocket and I'm getting error when trying to write to filestream.

```
async function test(...) {

    const websocket = new WebSocket(wsUrl)
    
    await connection(websocket)
    websocket.send(msg_json)
    
    let message = getMessage("Sent")
    writeStream.write(message)
    ...
}
```

Server gets message as expected
When I comment out the writeStream.write line code works without error.
However with this line I get the following error:

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:266:14)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:315:5)
    at test (single_test.js:56:29) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'
}
```

Can someone provide me some ideas how to save this message to log file?

Answer (score 0):

I used a walkaround by saving logs via bash commands as a temporary solution.